# covert Timestamp obj to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a datetime to float, but I'm getting an error

the code:

```
import pandas as pd
NameD = "03/02/2021 0:00"
NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).values.astype(float)
```

the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'values'
```

can you please help me to solve that error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `model`, or `jupyter` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). Also, please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). Code here is always supposed to be **minimal**, i.e. just enough to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.to_datetime(NameD) return a `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`, to get the value as an int, you can use pd.to_datetime(NameD).value

```
NameD = "03/02/2021 0:00"
NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).value
```

NameD now is an int, represents the number of nano seconds since 1 January 1970.
To get a unix timestamp, you can convert it to seconds by:

```
 NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).value * 10**-9
```

Comment: and to convert it to float `NameD = float(NameD)` thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to it convert into unix time. you can try **df.column.timestamp()**

```
import pandas as pd
NameD = "03/02/2021 0:00"
NameD = pd.to_datetime(NameD).timestamp()
print(NameD)
```

Output

```
1614643200.0
```